# Module output missing

Tags: r, shiny

The app is working, but the output in the modules are not showing. In this example, the `textOutput` in the `sumUI` and `sumSE` module doesn't work. I tried using the same logic as the reactives in the main server. For example, `input$var` in the sumSE like `input$select_data` in the main server. Things work in the main server, but don't seem to work in the module server. Is there a reason why?

```
library(shiny)

sumUI <- function(id, df) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column(4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(df())),
                    textOutput(NS(id, "test")))))
}


sumSE <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(df()[[input$var]])
     output$test <- renderPrint({
       data()
     })
  })
}

list_data <- tibble::lst(islands, iris, mtcars)

ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("select_data", "Select Data", choices = c(" ", names(list_data))),
    actionButton("add", "Add New"),
    verbatimTextOutput("output_text"),
    div(id = "add_here")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  add_id <- reactiveVal(0)  
  
  df <- reactive(
    get(input$select_data)
  )
  
  output$output_text <- renderPrint({
    input$select_data
  })
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    sumSE(id = paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()), df = df)
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = sumUI(paste0("sum_", input$add+add_id()), df = df))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I mixed up the ids!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)

sumUI <- function(id, df) {
    tagList(
        fluidRow(column(4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(df())),
                        textOutput(NS(id, "test")))))
}


sumSE <- function(id, df) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        data <- reactive(df()[[input$var]])
        output$test <- renderPrint({
            data()
        })
    })
}

list_data <- tibble::lst(islands, iris, mtcars)

ui <- function(request){
    fluidPage(
        selectInput("select_data", "Select Data", choices = c(" ", names(list_data))),
        actionButton("add", "Add New"),
        verbatimTextOutput("output_text"),
        div(id = "add_here")
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    add_id <- reactiveVal(0)  
    
    df <- reactive({
        req(input$select_data != " ")
        get(input$select_data)
    })
    
    output$output_text <- renderPrint({
        input$select_data
    })
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        sumSE(id = paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()), df = df)
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = sumUI(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()), df = df))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There are 2 things.

1. Your ids for UI and server must be the same.
2. You need to prevent empty values in the `df <- reactive(...`, otherwise it will crash the app if you click `add` right after app starts.